# Run a job for every one hour in java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I have to run a job using a thread for every 1 hour. This job is to read files in a folder. I have created a simple thread

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000*60*60);
                //Implementation
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
        }
    }
};
t.start();
```

which runs every one hour so that I can call the function to read the files. I want to know if this approach is good or any other approach is good

Comment: Use a scheduler. Look at [quartz scheduler](https://quartz-scheduler.org/). It will make your life easier :)

Comment: Or [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) for this task, and here is a [Sample Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use just `Thread` then try

```
try {
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 60);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
```

otherwise its a good choice that you can go with **[ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)**

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = ...

executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(someTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOUR);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyTimer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OneHourJob hourJob = new OneHourJob();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(hourJob, 0, 5000 * 60 * 60); // this code
        // runs every 5 seconds to make it one hour use this value 5000 * 60 *
        // 60
    }
}

class OneHourJob extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Ran after one hour.");

    }

}
```

Above code runs every five seconds. Whatever work you need to do write that code in run method of OneHourJob